# Getting invalid push tokens from firebase initially and at last gets a valid push token

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I have integrated FCM in my IOS application. I have added both Development and Production push certificate in the Firebase console. I have been developing the application for the last 1 year. Everything was working fine before 2/3 months back.

I installed the application in the device and received a token from firebase and when I tried to send the notification to this token. It is showing as InvalidRegistration/Not Registered. When I run my application, say for 3/4 times, I will get new push tokens which are also invalid ones and at last, I will get the valid push token.

I updated the Firebase, regenerated new push certificates but still the same issue. Is there anything I need to do in order​ to receive the valid push token and hence the notifications.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You have two Certificates types, the old .p12 and the new p8 certificate. 
The .p12 certificate is only valid for 1 year, the p8 a lot longer.

When you create your certificates, make sure that you upload your certificates to apple and Firebase.

I recommend to use the new p8 certificate.

Comment: I have uploaded the .p12 certificates. I have renewed those and uploaded the updated certificates. But still, the issue persists

Comment: Cleared all the existing code, removed pods. And wrote the fresh code by referring to the latest Firebase documentation. And thus everything worked well. Now I am getting valid tokens.